# Microsoft Security Essentials: MpCmdRun.exe -SignatureUpdate -unc switch does not work

Tags: windows, anti-virus, ms-security-essentials

[Looking here](http://rafaelwolf.com/?p=725) I can see extracting a downloaded mpam-fe.exe and copying the files to a shared folder should allow me to run the following command from an MSE client so it will pull down the updates from the share:

MpCmdRun.exe -SignatureUpdate -"\myserver\MSE-Defs"

This does not work. When I run this and check the log (C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\MpCmdRun.log) I see:

```
MpCmdRun: Command Line: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\MpCmdRun.exe"   -SignatureUpdate -"\\myserver\mse\"
 Start Time: ‎Fri ‎Sep ‎27 ‎2013 08:52:07

Start: MpSignatureUpdate()
Update started 
Search Started (MU/WU update) (Path: http://www.microsoft.com)...
```

So its totally ignoring the switch and going out to http://www.microsoft.com. If I remove the default gateway from this computer's NIC config the update fails.

How do I actually make MSE pull down definitions from a UNC path?

edit: I know I can just run mpam-fe.exe and it will update, but I'm still curious about how to make the unc switch work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command that you're running is not the command that the tutorial is telling you to run. You're missing the string "UNC"

```
MpCmdRun.exe -SignatureUpdate -UNC "\\myserver\MSE-Defs"
```

I don't know whether this is going to be Windows 8 specific, but when I tried it I had to have an x64 folder within the share, and I also had to include a path flag so my command looked like the following:

```
MpCmdRun.exe -SignatureUpdate -UNC -path "\\myserver\MSE-Defs"
```

I'd downloaded the mpam-fex64.exe file and placed it into \\myserver\MSE-Defs\x64